# Electron running js script on Windows causes "Check failed: result" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I am trying to run the following command:

```
C:\test\resources\dist\bin\electron\electron.exe
C:\test\resources\app.asar\assets\serviceinstaller install "Microsoft Print to PDF" "test_hahu@test.com"
```

But I am getting the following message:

```
Error: Command failed: C:\test\resources\dist\bin\electron\electron.exe C:\test\resources\app.asar\assets\serviceinstaller install "Microsoft Print to PDF" "test_hahu@eprinter.com"
 [3204:0412/194310.130:FATAL:icu_util.cc(292)] Check failed: result. 
 Backtrace:
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6AD508905+23093]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6AD578A63+482195]
 (No symbol) [0x00007FF6AD500554]
 (No symbol) [0x00007FF6AD4FF593]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6AD8518D1+3467777]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6AD5FB92D+1018461]
 (No symbol) [0x00007FF6AD258EDC]
 IsSandboxedProcess [0x00007FF6B04CCF37+46632271]
 BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF81AEF2784+20]
 RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF81D4A0D51+33]
```

The code inside the javascript installs a service which uses node-windows under the hood to install a service, but it fails with this message.

I have also tried with `asar = false`, nothing changes. If I need to provide more info or context, let me know.